# What does it mean by "in twelve months time"?

Tags: meaning

E.g. You can update your application in twelve months time.

What does it mean by "in twelve months time"?

Does it mean within twelve months or after twelve months?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In twelve months' time means that *after* twelve months you will be able to update the application. If they had meant you could change it *within* 12 months then they would have said something like "You can update your application *for/within* 12 months."